# Meteor Cordova App, Defining A Reactive Global Collection Object

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am trying to understand the best way of defining a global collection object across a set of different collections and routes. Basically I want to have a variable that correlates to a specific entry in a collection.

```
 foo = Collection.findOne({name:"foo"});
```

So that `foo` is a global object. Unfortunately foo is not reactive when used in a helper, i.e.

```
Template.show.helpers({
   value : function () {
       return foo;
   }
```

Returns `undefined`, however if `Collection` is queryed in the console it shows that there is in fact a value for the object with the `name:"foo`. This is because `foo` is set before the subscription to the Collection is finished.

I can also assign the value in a helper, but this way seems dirty and not correct:

```
foo = null;
Template.show.helpers({
   setFoo : function () {
       foo = Collection.findOne({name:"foo"});
   }
```

Lastly I tried using Iron:Router to wait on the subscription, but I still have the same problem. Also using iron-routers wait posses another problem if the Cordova app is offline the route will never even render due to the subscription wait. I also tried to set the vaiable using the `data` context but it also posses the same problem as before.

Ultimately my question is how can I declare a global reactive variable that doesn't depend on routes or waiting on subscriptions. Is `ReactiveVar an option and if so how would I use it in this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: when you call `findOne` on the collection, it registers the helper as a "dependant computation". So you should call it as `findOne` inside your helpers or use `ReactiveVar` if you want to be able to change it later.

Comment: @imslavko Why isn't my variable a "dependent computation" when I globally define it outside of any helpers `foo = Collection.findOne({name:"foo"});`

Comment: this might explain the system better than I can do in comments: http://manual.meteor.com/